# how to fetch friend's birthday details in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

Hi all
i am new to iphone app development world!!
i am working on an iphone application and trying to fetch friends B'Day details from fbConnect.

can anyone please guide me as how to do this.
i have shown friends list in UITableView but could not understand as how to get their Birth date.

Any help is more than welcome

Answer (score 0):

Googling gave me this SO question: [Facebook: Unable to get users' birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771474/facebook-unable-to-get-users-birthday/2774086#2774086)

Edit: Apparently it's not a simple web api as i thought. But i think you should look for user_birthday on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/. I got there from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios, and i believe you can request birthdays just like you request other things.

If this does not work, can you show me how you request other data?

Edit 2: Try out this SO question: [Starting out with an application for Facebook Connect on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498631/starting-out-with-an-application-for-facebook-connect-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Thanks Erik...actually i searched it but as this solution is for Php Users thats why i could not understand it properly. as i understand only c, c++ and objective C. is there any solution for objective C?

Comment: hey Eric..did u got smthin..some API..
i got to knw that it would be done through FQL but still couldn't find that how to use FQL in objective C for birthday date